# How do I retrieve a one-to-one association in a sails.js controller for list/index views?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sails.js

Just getting started with sails.js - how do I retrieve a one-to-one association with the following models as an example? I think I have the single view taken care of but struggling with list views. It seems possible with a controller alone or for more flexibility use a service but syntax in both scenarios is my stumbling block... I keep getting **undefined** or **nothing at all**...

#### User.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    displayName: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true
    },
    username: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    email: {
      type: 'email',
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 8
    },
    profile: function(callback) {
      Person
        .findByUserId(this.id)
        .done(function(err, profile) {
          callback(profile);
        });
    },
    // Override toJSON instance method to remove password value
    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      delete obj.confirmation;
      delete obj.plaintextPassword;
      delete obj.sessionId;
      delete obj._csrf;
      return obj;
    },
  }
};
```

#### Person.js (used as profile if userId present)

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    userId: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    firstName: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    // Override toJSON instance method to remove password value
    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.sessionId;
      delete obj._csrf;
      return obj;
    }
  }
};
```

#### UserController.js

```
  show: function(req, res) {
    var userId = req.param('id');
    async.parallel({
      profile: function(callback) {
        UserService.getProfileForUser(userId, callback);
      },
      user: function(callback) {
        UserService.getUser(userId, callback);
      }
    },
    function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
        res.send(error.status ? error.status : 500, error.message ? error.message : error);
      } else {
        data.layout = req.isAjax ? "layout_ajax" : "layout";
        data.userId = userId;
        res.view(data);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a one-to-one association between two models, you don't need to write your own custom function; it's built into Sails. See the [Sails docs](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/OnetoOne.html) for more details.

User.js

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  profile: {
    model: person;
  },
  ...
}
```

Person.js

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  user: {
    model: 'user'
  },
  ...
}
```

UserController.js

```
show: function(req, res) {
  var userId = req.param('id');
  User.findOne(userId).populate('profile').exec(function (err, user) {
    if (error) {
      res.send(error.status ? error.status : 500, error.message ? error.message : error);
    } else {
      var profile = user.profile;
      var data = { user: user, profile: profile };
      data.layout = req.isAjax ? "layout_ajax" : "layout";
      data.userId = userId;
      res.view(data);
    }
  });
}
```